# Add variables to array from a number of structures

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a kinda specific problem here:

I have a structure with 120 variables, each variable with varying number of rows (but fixed number of columns = 7)

I need to create a new array of the first 2 columns from all the arrays.

The problem I am having is appending the new set of numbers below the first.

Is there a way to do this without eval?

I was trying something like this:

```
varr = fieldnames(sctData);

for ii = 1:size(sctData,1)
   m = 1;
   for m = m:m+eval(['size(sctData.' varr{ii} ',1)'])

       eval(['sctData2(m,1) = sctData.' varr{ii} '(m,1);']);
       eval(['sctData2(m,2) = sctData.' varr{ii} '(m,2);']);

   end

end
```

But ofcourse, this rewrites the variables over the old one. And I really don't want to use eval!

Any help is welcome. :)
Thanks!

Comment: You can access fields of a struct with the field name by putting parentheses around the string like: `sctData.(var{ii})`. This can be used both for accessing and assigning values - and should hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work if I understood your question correctly:

```
varr = struct2cell(sctData);

newarray = [];

for ii = 1:length(varr)
    temp = varr{ii};
    newarray = [newarray; temp(:,1:2)];
end
```